# How to Install new module, add code to existing module that requires the new module, and import config for the new module in the same build

Tags: configuration, installation

I seem to be running into a circular dependency issue in the scenario where my new build has a new module (B), new code in an existing module (A) that depends on the new module (B) and new config being imported for the new module (B).

In the past I have handled this with creating and deploying two independent builds, one where I deploy the new modules and enable them, and in the second build, deploy code that requires the new modules and the config for the new modules.

Is there a better way to handle this?

The change in Module A is that one of the services in Module A requires a service from Module B.

I have already added dependency to the new module B in module_A.info.yml file but that does not help as the module is already installed.

`drush en module_b` does not work and it gives the error.

```
The service "module_A_service" has a dependency on a non-existent service "module_B_service".
```

The config import that is in the build has core.extensions updated to enable module_B when it is imported but config import with `drush cim` is failing with the same error as above.

Comment: I have done what you have done. You can also think about detecting the other module or service and falling back onto some basic behavior.

Comment: It sounds like you want to add a `hook_update_N` in module_A to install module_B

Comment: Thanks for the responses @cilefen

Aren't service dependencies kind of hard in the way the dependencies are added in the yml files?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Clive - I didn't explicitly try that, but I tried a drush php eval of \Drupal::service('module_installer')->install(['module_b']);. That gave the same error. Would it behave differently in hook_update. I could try that as well.

Comment: The error indicates that your A service has a dependency that does not exist, which is not a circular dependency. What is the error if you deploy everything in one commit, rather than splitting it into two?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jaypan. drush cr fails with the above error. drush cim also fails with the same error. drush updb runs but shows the same error. I am not deploying this in multiple builds. I am deploying in a single build. What I was saying was that I usually address this issue with two builds and was trying to figure out what would be a good way to address this in one single build.

Comment: If this is from a single deploy, try using Drush to enable Module B first, then run `drush updb`.

Comment: drush en module_b was failing with the same error as above. However I went ahead and added a hook update with the \Drupal::service('module_installer')->install(['module_b']); like what @Clive suggested. It went through without errors and installed the module. So the solution is to add a hook update to explicitly enable the dependent module even though the build has the config to enable the module later.

Comment: I think `updb` does run under a different bootstrap mode so it's worth a shot if you're able to test first (just pulling DB/public files down and running locally should let you do that). I'm pretty sure I've done exactly this before to solve the same problem. Maybe don't do a `drush cr` before the `updb`, so the system doesn't get a chance to rebuild the plugin cache until the module is enabled

Comment: Thanks @Clive. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution that worked

a) Implement a hook_update_N in module A that is already installed. In the hook_update_N add code to install module_b. Include this in the same build.

```
function module_a_update_NNNN(&$sandbox) {
  $module_installer = \Drupal::service('module_installer');
  $module_handler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
  if (!$module_handler->moduleExists('module_b')) {
    $module_installer->install(['module_b']);
  }
}
```

b) Deploy the build

c) Do not clear cache. If you run cache clear before updb it will throw the same error as mentioned in the question.

d) Run `drush updb`

e) Run `drush cim`

f) Run `drush cr`